# Determining what import triggers a dll in PyInstaller analysis

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm trying to figure out why PyInstaller keeps including Windows dll files for PyQt even though my application doesn't use PyQt.  So, I'd like to know how to determine *why* PyInstaller thinks PyQt is necessary or more generally what .py files in my application lead to what dll files in the completed build.

I'm currently using PyInstaller 2.1 on a Windows Machine and building a command-line only application with the following dependencies:

- numpy==1.8.0
- numexpr==2.3.1
- Cython==0.20.1
- scipy==0.13.3
- scikit-image==0.9.3
- tables==3.1.1
- Sphinx==1.2.1
- pylint==1.1.0
- pytest==2.5.2
- pytest-cov==1.6
- rst2pdf==0.93.dev
- line-profiler==1.0b3
- ipython==2.1.0

I don't think any of these strictly require PyQt except for IPython.  However,
I'm not sure if IPython really imports PyQt at runtime or not.  There were too
many imports to track down in the main IPython/**init**.py.

I've manually edited my PyInstaller spec file to add PyQt4 to the Analysis
excludes.  This seems to work just fine, but I don't want to manually edit this
spec file every time I make a build.  I'd prefer to figure out why PyQt4 is
included anyway?

Also, it's worth noting that including PyQt4 doesn't necessarily hurt anything,
but it does make my final distribution directory quite a bit bigger than I
think it needs to be.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No, still never figured it out. My best guess is pyinstaller was taking everything on sys.path or something.  You have any theories?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you have Anaconda installed by chance? When I build an exe on my computer it just includes the relevant packages, but on my colleague's computer, which has Anaconda installed, we run into this problem.

This still does not explain why, though. If I get some time I'll see if I can get any help from the Pyinstaller folks, they are very helpful.

Comment: Hmm that's a good thing to look into. I can't remember if I ran into this using Anaconda or not, my best guess is I was using Anaconda. Maybe this happens because Anaconda hacks sys.path and does some weird environment stuff Pyinstaller doesn't expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a detailed view of all the imports, what triggered what to be included, etc. by running pyinstaller with the `--log-level DEBUG` argument and looking in the `build\<exe_name>\xref-<exe_name_>.html` file.

If you're running Pyinstaller 3.3 or above this file will always be written regardless of the log level. [Pyinstaller 3.3 release notes](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases/tag/v3.3)